# How do you generate a random number in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, random

I would like to generate a random floating point number between 2 values.  What is the best way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The only thing I'd add to [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408/how-do-you-generate-a-random-number-in-c#44428)'s response is an explanation; I feel that knowledge of why code works is better than knowing what code works.

The explanation is this: let's say you want a number between 2.5 and 4.5.  The range is 2.0 (4.5 - 2.5).  `NextDouble` only returns a number between 0 and 1.0, but if you multiply this by the range you will get a number between 0 and *range*.

So, this would give us random doubles between 0.0 and 2.0:

```
rng.NextDouble() * 2.0
```

But, we want them between 2.5 and 4.5!  How do we do this?  Add the smallest number, 2.5:

```
2.5 + rng.NextDouble() * 2.0
```

Now, we get a number between 0.0 and 2.0; if you add 2.5 to each of these values we see that the range is now between 2.5 and 4.5.

At first I thought that it mattered if b > a or a > b, but if you work it out both ways you'll find it works out identically so long as you don't mess up the order of the variables used.  I like to express it with longer variable names so I don't get mixed up:

```
double NextDouble(Random rng, double min, double max)
{
    return min + (rng.NextDouble() * (max - min));
}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
System.Random r = new System.Random();

double rnd( double a, double b )
{
   return a + r.NextDouble()*(b-a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// generate a random number starting with 5 and less than 15
Random r = new Random();
int num = r.Next(5, 15);
```

For doubles you can replace Next with NextDouble

Comment: That isn't actually accurate. NextDouble generates only between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: NextDouble() takes no arguments from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

How random?  If you can deal with pseudo-random then simply:

```
Random randNum = new Random();
randNum. NextDouble(Min, Max);
```

If you want a "better" random number, then you probably should look at the Mersenne Twister algorithm.  Plenty of people hav [already implemented it](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MersenneTwister) for you though

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of how to get Cryographically safe random numbers:
This will fill in the 8 bytes with a crytographically strong sequence of random values.

```
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
rng.GetBytes(salt);
```

For more details see [How Random is your Random??"](http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/content/archive/2007/12/05/how-random-is-your-random.aspx) (inspired by a CodingHorror article on deck shuffling)

Answer (score 1):

For an explaination of why Longhorn has been downmodded so much: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163367.aspx Look for the implementation of NextDouble and the explanation of what is a random double.

That link is also a goo example of how to use cryptographic random numbers (like Sameer mentioned) only with actual useful outputs instead of a bit stream.