# random double in four different interval

Tags: c#, random

By my need in my application, I need to generate number from range 0 to 1, but with a little modify :

```
1. Range [0,1) : include 0 but not 1
2. Range (0, 1) : not include 0 nor 1
3. Range (0, 1] : same as 1. include 1 but not 0
4. Range [0,1]: include both 0 and 1
```

In C#, how can I random like this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you're creating a `double`-precision random number, the odds of exactly zero or exactly one coming up is vanishingly small. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: How about ["How do you generate a random number in C#?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408/how-do-you-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Comment: @Scony - the question you suggested does not talk about open/closed intervals for results...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov - Right, but it shows method. If you understand method, open/closed intervals are trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number one is easy, that's what's returned from the `NextDouble` method;

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double number = rnd.NextDouble();
```

To exclude the zero, pick a new number if you get a zero:

```
double number;
do {
  number = rnd.NextDouble();
} while(number == 0.0);
```

To include 1 but not 0, subtract the random number from 1:

```
double number = 1.0 - rnd.NextDouble();
```

To include both 0 and 1, you would use an approach similar to what King King suggests, with a sufficiently large number for your need:

```
double number = (double)rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue) / (Int32.MaxValue - 1);
```

(Using ints you can get 31 bits of precision. If you need more than that you would need to use `NextBytes` to get 8 bytes that you can turn into a long.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the precision you want, I suppose the precision is `0.001`, try this code:

```
var rand = new Random();
//1
var next = (float) rand.Next(1000)/1000;
//2
var next = (float) rand.Next(1,1000)/1000;
//3
var next = (float) rand.Next(1,1001)/1000;
//4
var next = (float) rand.Next(1001)/1000;
```